# How to find by array and return nil if not matched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this `before_filter` in one of my controllers:

```
def valid_people
  person_ids = params[:project][:person_ids]
  if person_ids.present?        
    person = current_user.people.where("id IN (?)", person_ids).to_a
    redirect_to(root_path) unless person
  end
end
```

Line 4 checks if all the `ids` in the `person_ids` array are contained in the user's `people`.

However, it throws an error if that's not the case.

How can I get line 4 to return `nil` instead?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're describing how obvious code works, in ~16 words. Then the real problem you're describing in ~10, moreover in very general way.

Comment: @Tintin81: Then why not just check if person contains something, i.e: `redirect_to(root_path) unless person.any?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `present?` or `blank?`. That also handles empty arrays:

```
redirect_to(root_path) if person.blank?
```

Btw: The variable `person` should be renamed to `people`, because it returns an array for people not just one person.